# Is one allowed to dine in a home where pots are kosher but not toiveled?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, tevilas-keilim-dipping, utensil

What would be the halachic course of action if one is invited for a meal on shabbos to a family who are shomer shabbos and kosher, but readily admit that they never toiveled their pots/dishes?

Is it forbidden to eat food prepared in untoiveled pots even if we use paper plates/cutlery?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/1933

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the preferred course of action is to eat from disposable utensils. In cases of extenuating need, one could rely on lenient opinions, but in all cases you should check with your Rabbi.

din.org.il [writes](https://din.org.il/en/2014/04/13/eating-from-non-toveled-dishes-2/)

> There is a problem with eating from non-toveled dishes, and **you should
> preferably ask to eat from disposable dishes. If this is impossible
> (for whatever reason), there is room for leniency** in eating from
> non-toveled dishes. It is more important to ensure toveled or
> disposable cutlery than dishes

R Chaim Tabasky at yeshiva.co [writes](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/1933)

> According to most Rishonim and Poskim there is a prohibition to use
> utensils that have not been Toveled. There is a minority opinion that
> there is a Mitzvah to Tovel, but no prohibition of use. According to
> some Poskim there is a prohibition, but only for the owner. The
> majority opinion is that there is a general prohibition.
>
> **In situations
> of embarrassment, or for the performance of a Mitzvah (e.g. drinking
> four cups of wine on Pesach), or when there is another extenuating
> circumstance, a guest in someone's home may rely on the minority
> opinion that use for persons other than the owner of the utensils is
> permitted** for the following reasons:
>
> 1. It is widely agreed that even if there is a prohibition of use it is Rabbinic.
> 2. Many materials used for utensils today do not require tevila according to all opinions.
> 3. Some hold that only utensils owned by a single non Jew require tevila, but that those sold by a company do not.
>
> This leniency does not apply if there is no extenuating circumstance.
> Since there are other factors about which utensils may not be used, a
> Rabbi should be consulted about particular cases. In any event, the
> food which was prepared in not toveled utensils is kosher and may be
> eaten.